# Programmatically get the complete XPath of an element from the document

Tags: javascript, android, ecmascript-6

Using NodeJS how can I get the complete XPath of an element, which I want to identify by its attributes - `Text`

Below is the XML:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='yes' ?>
<hierarchy index="0" class="hierarchy" rotation="0" width="1440" height="3036">
  <android.widget.FrameLayout index="0" package="com.google.android.permissioncontroller" class="android.widget.FrameLayout" text="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" bounds="[37,1017][1403,2102]" displayed="true">
    <android.widget.FrameLayout index="0" package="com.google.android.permissioncontroller" class="android.widget.FrameLayout" text="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" bounds="[37,1017][1403,2102]" displayed="true">
      <android.widget.FrameLayout index="0" package="com.google.android.permissioncontroller" class="android.widget.FrameLayout" text="" resource-id="android:id/content" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" bounds="[37,1017][1403,2102]" displayed="true">
        <android.widget.ScrollView index="0" package="com.google.android.permissioncontroller" class="android.widget.ScrollView" text="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="true" focused="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" bounds="[37,1017][1403,2102]" displayed="true">
          <android.widget.LinearLayout index="0" package="com.google.android.permissioncontroller" class="android.widget.LinearLayout" text="" resource-id="com.android.permissioncontroller:id/grant_singleton" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" bounds="[37,1017][1403,2102]" displayed="true">
            <android.widget.LinearLayout index="0" package="com.google.android.permissioncontroller" class="android.widget.LinearLayout" text="" resource-id="com.android.permissioncontroller:id/grant_dialog" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="true" focusable="true" focused="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" bounds="[37,1017][1403,2102]" displayed="true">
              <android.widget.LinearLayout index="0" package="com.google.android.permissioncontroller" class="android.widget.LinearLayout" text="" resource-id="com.android.permissioncontroller:id/content_container" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" bounds="[93,1073][1347,1549]" displayed="true">
                <android.widget.LinearLayout index="0" package="com.google.android.permissioncontroller" class="android.widget.LinearLayout" text="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" bounds="[177,1136][1263,1465]" displayed="true">
                  <android.widget.ImageView index="0" package="com.google.android.permissioncontroller" class="android.widget.ImageView" text="" resource-id="com.android.permissioncontroller:id/permission_icon" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" bounds="[664,1136][776,1248]" displayed="true" />
                  <android.widget.TextView index="1" package="com.google.android.permissioncontroller" class="android.widget.TextView" text="Allow App to send you notifications?" resource-id="com.android.permissioncontroller:id/permission_message" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" bounds="[177,1290][1263,1465]" displayed="true" />
                </android.widget.LinearLayout>
              </android.widget.LinearLayout>
              <android.widget.LinearLayout index="1" package="com.google.android.permissioncontroller" class="android.widget.LinearLayout" text="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" bounds="[93,1549][1347,2046]" displayed="true">
                <android.widget.Button index="0" package="com.google.android.permissioncontroller" class="android.widget.Button" text="Allow" resource-id="com.android.permissioncontroller:id/permission_allow_button" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="true" focusable="true" focused="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" bounds="[177,1556][1263,1752]" displayed="true" />
                <android.widget.Button index="1" package="com.google.android.permissioncontroller" class="android.widget.Button" text="Don’t allow" resource-id="com.android.permissioncontroller:id/permission_deny_button" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="true" focusable="true" focused="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" bounds="[177,1766][1263,1962]" displayed="true" />
              </android.widget.LinearLayout>
            </android.widget.LinearLayout>
          </android.widget.LinearLayout>
        </android.widget.ScrollView>
      </android.widget.FrameLayout>
    </android.widget.FrameLayout>
  </android.widget.FrameLayout>
</hierarchy>
```

I would like to get the XPath element of the first button with the text - `Allow`.
Expected XPath:
`/hierarchy/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.ScrollView/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout[2]/android.widget.Button[1]`

Comment: What would "complete" look like for this example? Please give the xpath you'd want to be generated.

Comment: Thanks. The expected XPath will be: `/hierarchy/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.ScrollView/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout[2]/android.widget.Button[1]`